# Jerk When reloading UITableView when User is in bottom of the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, reload

All,

I am facing some simple issue like i have multiple sections where i am display relevant data for each section, When ever there is a change in some `UIButton` action in One row, the data in the section changed based on it.

When i am in bottom of the`UITableView` if click on some button there is a reload happen and `UITableView` going to previous position (Section starting position). How can be we will be in same postion though we reload data.

Comment: did you get any solution?.@ashok Londhe

Answer (score 3):

After reload data , you can add the code to scrollToIndexPath here

```
//set your indexPath
NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.myTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1) inSection:0];

[[self myTable] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

I don't understand why there is jerk in tableview. Maybe you can reload just the cell you are changing. Try

```
NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
[myUITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: `animated:` is a bool in this case.... `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` does not equal 0... so that should be `[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];`

Answer (score 3):

I have observed that reloadData() function gives Jerk when you are not setting your **estimatedHeightForRowAt** properly. This function should return a value near to what you think your cells height would be. If the difference between you runtime cell height and the return value is too high then it gives a jerk while reloading tableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 400.0
    }
```

Set this value appropriately and it will not jerk. Many people think that you can just pass any value to it and it doesn't matter but it is not like that.

I am passing 400 over here because my cell height varies from 350-400 to any value like 1200-1300. So 400 estimated value is working perfectly fine. I tried with 100 but then it jerks because value 100 is inappropriate.